# Why Bluetooth Module is not discoverable from android Bluetooth client?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have the used the code in [this example](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) for android Bluetooth communication, and it works fine in two android devices.

But I have a hardware that uses this [Bluetooth module](http://www.parallax.com/tabid/768/productid/550/default.aspx). the device is discovered by J2ME application. But when searching about it using the previous android application, the application couldn't discover the Bluetooth module. what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the class of Bluetooth module. Some android OS blocks class id 0